# Dynamic PSD threshold for FFT

Tags: fourier-transform

I am using signal denoising as explained by [Steve Brunton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2K1JfNR7Sc), who explains that FFT is data data-driven SVD.

I can select important components by selecting singular values that capture 90% of the variance in SVD.

Can I dynamically compute the threshold (without any PSD visualization) of PSD when I decompose a signal using FFT?